# Can the canonical tag be used on all pages?

Tags: html, seo, canonical-link

Im working on a site that has had an SEO expert review it. They have advised me that we should apply `canonical` tags on every other page

```
<!-- http://www.example.com/detail/table&r=dining-room -->

<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/detail/table"/>
```

is it really required that the `canonical` tag only appears on every other page, or will it play nicely if it appears on the same page?

The reason I ask this is: isn't the link also telling Google that it is infact on the right page?

Comment: Canonical tags are for telling google that two pages have same or near enough the same content, so example.com/page-one has the same content as example.com/page.php?id=1, the canonical tag will go to either pointing to the other.

Comment: thanks for that, what im wondering is... is there any negative effect for having the link tag on the page its referring to ? or is it ignored because this is the actual page the link tag is referencing ?

Comment: It's to tell search engines your preferred page. check here http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html and http://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*RFC 6596: The Canonical Link Relation* [specifies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596#section-3):

> The target (canonical) IRI MAY:
> o […]
> o Be self-referential (context IRI identical to target IRI).

So, yes, you can use `rel`-`canonical` even on the canonical page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an argument between Google and Bing. Google doesn't mind if you have the canonical tag pointing to itself. Bing does mind and you lose their trust for the use of canonical tags. Look at this article: http://www.northsideseo.com/google-vs-bing-canonical-tag/