# How to set canonical URL for 2 part blog entry?

Tags: pagination, seo, canonical-link

I have a blog with Photoshop tutorials and because some of my tutorials are quite long I've decided to split the content into parts

```
http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx

http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx?part=2
```

and set the `canonical` rel for both pages to

```
http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx
```

Is this better than the option of having 2 canonical links? Please note that I have images and text on both parts that I would like to have indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not allowed to use the `canonical` link type in that case.

[RFC 6596 defines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596#section-3):

> The target (canonical) IRI MUST identify content that is either duplicative or a superset of the content at the context (referring) IRI.

But your second page is not included in (or identical to) the first page.

So you have these options:

- Introduce a page that contains the whole content, and make this one the `canonical` target for all paginated pages (but if you do this, you might want to consider to stop offering the paginated versions in the first place). Note that this is only allowed if the paginated pages [don’t have separate user comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45609/24166) (or any other unique content).
- Use [self-referential](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20437674/1591669) `canonical` targets.
- Omit `canonical`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use canonical for pagination for solve that:

1. In the `<head>` section of the first page (www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx), 
   add a link tag pointing to the next page in the sequence, like this:

   ```
   <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx">
   <link rel="next" href="http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx?part=2">
   ```

   Because this is the first URL in the sequence, there’s no need to add markup for rel="prev".
2. On the second and third pages, add links pointing to the previous and next URLs in the sequence. For example, you could add the following to the second page of the sequence:

   ```
   <link rel="prev" href="http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx">
   <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx?part=2">
   <link rel="next" href="http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx?part=3">
   ```

3. On the final page of the sequence (www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx?part=4>), add a link pointing to the previous URL, like this:

   ```
   <link rel="prev" href="http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx?part=3">
   <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-coffee-stain-text-in-photoshop.aspx?part=4">
   ```

   Because this is the final URL in the sequence, there’s no need to add a rel="next" link.