# Automatic canonical tag if GET parameters defined

Tags: php, html, seo, canonical-link

I was doing some research into page duplicate content for dynamic keyword insertion via a GET parameter if definded, if not it will default to a definded value.

Would it be a benefit to set up a quick PHP check in the page head where by if a GET parameter is present it will automatically insert a canonical tag with the GET parameters stripped out?

Will this solve the issue of duplicate content for the page(s)?

It's worth mentioning the dynamic GET parameters will only be present when passed by ad networks such as AdWords.

Comment: You could provide the `canonical` link [even on the canonical pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20437674/1591669). So this would save you the check, no?

Comment: But if you was todo that it would be saying that the original page is a duplicate of itself? Would it not?

Comment: `canonical` doesn’t mean "duplicate", it means: this is the canonical (e.g., "preferred") URL for the document. If the current document and the `canonical` URL are the same, the visitor/bot knows: this is the URL I should use

Comment: Okay with you - Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is certainly possible, but there is an even better solution: *always* provide the `canonical` URL, [even if it’s self-referential](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20437674/1591669).

```html
<!-- on                     http://example.com/posts/1 -->
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/posts/1">
```

```html
<!-- on                     http://example.com/posts/1?tracking=123 -->
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/posts/1">
```

```html
<!-- on                     http://example.com/posts//////1?a-URL-you-never-expected -->
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/posts/1">
```

Benefits:

- Covers all cases of URL variants, not just the expected parameters.
- No PHP check needed.
- Consumers that directly land on your canonical variant can be sure that it’s the canonical URL, thanks to the explicit markup.